# YAML List of Unnamed Strings With Optional Boolean

Tags: go, yaml

I want to define YAML that defines a list of strings by default.  I don't want this list of strings to be a named attribute.  I also want to have an optional boolean parameter.  As in

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type ThingAndGroups struct {
    Groups   []string
    boolval  boolean
}

var someStr = `
thing1:
  - g1
  - g2
  boolval:
    y

thing2:
  - g1
  - g2
`

func main() {
    t := make(map[string]ThingAndGroups)

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(someStr), &t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t:\n%v\n\n", t)
}
```

Would then return

> map[thing1:{[g1, g2] true}, thing2:{[g1, g2] false}]

Is that possible?

I DO NOT want to define the YAML as

```
var someStr = `
thing1:
  groups:
    - g1
    - g2
  boolval:
    y`
```

And if the YAML didn't have boolval I could just do

```
 func main() {
    // NOTE THIS IS A MAP
    t := make(map[string][]string)

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(someStr), &t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t:\n%v\n\n", t)
}
```

Comment: Just in case you wanted to try something other than yaml, I would suggest HCL (much like nginx conf and based on UCL). So far not problem using it: https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl.

Comment: Your desired yaml is not valid, it won't parse. So, it's use the more readable form later (which can still go in the same go struct) or give up on yaml.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

- Defining a YAML sequence without using a mapping key.

### Solution

- Change BEFORE into AFTER

#### BEFORE

```
  var someStr = `
  thing1:
    - g1
    - g2
    boolval:
      y

  thing2:
    - g1
    - g2
  `
```

#### AFTER

```
  var someStr = `
  thing1:
    - g1
    - g2
    - boolval: y

  thing2:
    - g1
    - g2
  `
```

#### Pitfalls

- This approach is not desirable because it uses the YAML sequence to store two different kinds of data (the groups and the boolean value).
- Another answer (that was later deleted) suggested using a groups key, and that was a good suggestion.