# YAML/GoLang Mix Top Level Map Second Level Optional Bool

Tags: go, yaml

I want to define YAML that defines a list of strings by default.  I don't want this list of strings to be a named attribute.  I also want to have an optional boolean parameter.  As in

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type ThingAndGroups struct {
    Groups   []string
    boolval  boolean
}

var someStr = `
thing1:
  - g1
  - g2
  boolval:
    y

thing2:
  - g1
  - g2
`

func main() {
    t := make(map[string]ThingAndGroups)

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(someStr), &t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t:\n%v\n\n", t)
}
```

Would then return

> map[thing1:{[g1, g2] true}, thing2:{[g1, g2] false}]

Is that possible?

I DO NOT want to define the YAML as

```
var someStr = `
thing1:
  groups:
    - g1
    - g2
  boolval:
    y`
```

And if the YAML didn't have boolval I could just do

```
 func main() {
    // NOTE THIS IS A MAP
    t := make(map[string][]string)

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(someStr), &t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t:\n%v\n\n", t)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YAML List of Unnamed Strings With Optional Boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835778/yaml-list-of-unnamed-strings-with-optional-boolean)

Comment: Just in case you wanted to try something other than yaml, I would suggest HCL (much like nginx conf and based on UCL). So far not problem using it: https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl.